# Pyqt QCameraInfo.availableCameras() is empty

Tags: python, camera, qt

I'm doing a small project on Raspberry Pi 4. Also, I want to use `QtMultimedia` to list all cameras on pi, But it returns an empty list.

```
# This is my testing code

from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QCameraInfo

print(QCameraInfo.availableCameras())
```

I already took a picture via use `raspistill` so the camera is works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read available cameras in PyQt5, you need to install `Qt 5 Multimedia module plugins`

```
$ apt install libqt5multimedia5-plugins
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *

cmara=QCameraInfo()
for i in cmara.availableCameras():
    print(i.description())
```